# What does "For the record" mean?

Tags: meaning

Can anybody help me with that?
I've had a look at dictionary and yahoo search before but I can't find out 
what does exactly "for the record mean"

Foe example:

> And for the record he wasn't agreed with that

Comment: Does this help? http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+the+record

Comment: AfterLife, have you already thought to follow English Language Learners (ell.stackexchange.com)? Please, take a look; you may be interested in. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It means something like "I should just state that..." or "I just want to make clear that..." or "it should be noted that..."